# python nested list comprehension with all() or any()

Tags: python-3.x

I have two list and I wanted to use the element of list2 in a condition to check against the element in list1.

```
list1 = ['antxyz', 'bear456', 'catabc', 'dog0xy', 'zebraayc']
list2 = ['cat', 'dog']
```

My original code works like this:

```
all('cat' in item or 'dog' in item for item in list2)
True

any('cat' in item or 'dog' in item for item in list1)
True
```

Now instead of using individual strings (cat or dog) in the condition, I wanted to put these strings in list2 and use it for condition checking against list1. How do I do that?

So far I have created a nested list like this which seems to get me closer to what I need but I can't figure out how to enclose it in all() or any() function.

```
for item2 in list2:
    for item1 in list1:
        if item2 in item1:
            print(item2 + ' found in ' + item1)
        else:
            print(item2 + ' not found in ' + item1)

dog not found in antxyz
dog not found in bear456
dog not found in catabc
dog found in dog0xy
dog not found in zebraayc
cat not found in antxyz
cat not found in bear456
cat found in catabc
cat not found in dog0xy
cat not found in zebraayc
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for item2 in list2:
>     for item1 in list1:
>         if item2 in item1:
>             print(item2 + ' found in ' + item1)
>         else:
>             print(item2 + ' not found in ' + item1)`
> ```

Instead of using nested loops, you can reduce it further. Also for faster look-up,we can change the list1 to set.
so, code for this :

```
list1 = {'ant', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog', 'zebra'}

for element in list2:
      if element in list1:
             print('Found!!')
```

Also suggested by Jab, you can use **issubset()** method of [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to check it directly.

> s.issubset(t)  or s <= t  : test whether every element in s is in t

As per your requirement, it is :

```
list2.issubset(list1)
```